# How to prevent an item from being used more than a certain count?

Tags: c#, caching, concurrency

Trying to implement a `ConcurrentQueue` that prevents an item from being used more than a specific # of times. For example, I want a User object that can be Dequeued 10 times, and after that, the user would be logged off and disposed.

Obviously fairly easy to implement by using a `Dictionary` and keeping track of the number of times each object has been used, in conjunction with the `ConcurrentQueue`. However, just wondering if anybody has any neat ideas for managing this?

Comment: simplest would be to create a base class for your objects that go in the queue that is of some type (Countable for instance) that contains use count, and create a wrapper for the dequeue that reduces the count from 10 and once it hits zero do your logic, there's probably better ways to do this i think

Comment: unfortunately the type that I am using in the ConcurrentQueue currently is defined by someone else, and is an interface, so I don't think I can go that route.

Comment: Dictionary would be your best bet in that case, wrap the Dequeue in something that checks the dictionary for the use count and does the rest of the logic accordingly. Dictionary will be quite small (memory wise) compared to your objects anyway (unless you have ALOT of objects).

Comment: Is it necessary to use that particular interface by name?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this in java:

```
interface Dequeable
{
    public int dequed();
}

class ConcurrentQueueImpl extends ConcurrentQueue
{
    ..................
    .................

    @override
    public Dequeable deque()
    {
        Dequeable obj=.................;

        **if(obj.dequed()>=10)**
        {
            // dispose off obj
            return null;
        }
        return obj;
    }

}

class SampleDequeableClass implements Dequeable
{
    private int dequedCounter=0;
    public int dequed()
    {
        dequedCounter++;
        if(dequedCounter>=10)
        {
            // log off this object...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you would have read the comments you would see that he already said he can't do this because I made this exact suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own thread-safe `Queue<T>`, just like the days without C#4.0. And in its `Dequeue` method, record the use count. You needn't modify the original class/interface of the item. You can have another `Dictionary<IFoo, int>` as a use counter.